# Lost Directory structure

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Made a stupid typo and moved all my directories into cyberspace and have no idea where they went I accidentally moved them into /etc/Public but when I tried to move them to ~/Public they are no way to be found! Does anyone know of anyway to list the entire directory structure recursively so I can find where they went to?

andy

Answer (score 0):

You may have lost them, but if you **really** want to list all of the directory structure you can just:

```
find /
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to save that to a file,

```
find / > ~/file
```

will save that file to your Personal Folder.

Comment: That might help... how to i put that into a searchable file?

Comment: Also I am running Ubuntu 14.04, are there any graphical interfaces for dealing with files without installing the entire desktop? It seems to me just a simple typo can really mess things up ;-)

Comment: Yes, you can use Nautilus, Ubuntu's file manager